# Web based file sharing/management for small office?

Tags: network-share, web

We are a small company what are looking for a way to share documents and files on our dedicated ubuntu server. It has to be web based and it would be nice if you could search for files and enter basic metadata about the files. We prefer if the solution is based on php+mysql.

We are looking for something like PHPfileNavigator but that one is no longer under development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[KnowledgeTree](http://www.knowledgetree.com) is probably the best free document management system for Linux that I'm aware of, but it can be kind of a bear to install. [Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com) has a lot of features, but is really designed more as an enterprise DMS than something to be used by departments or small companies. [OpenKM](http://www.openkm.com) is a newcomer with a fancy AJAX interface I've been seeing pop up more and more, but I haven't personally used it.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried AjaXplorer? http://www.ajaxplorer.info/

But I think, better to use samba in such cases.

Answer (score 1):

There's [File Thingie](http://www.solitude.dk/filethingie/) which is a PHP based file manager.

Or why don't you try installing a wiki and attach files to the wiki pages? We use TWiki which is perl based but better than the PHP one's I've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Most wikis and content management solutions will give you the functionality you're looking for.  I like Plone for it's rich metadata and searching capabilities, but it's a big hammer if all you need is file sharing.  We use Confluence (and have used Mediawiki) at my office and they both work for this sort of thing (although Confluence in particular isn't necessarily pretty as far as file management goes).

Some solutions offer WebDAV access, which is nice because both Windows and OS X can mount WebDAV volumes on the desktop just like other disks.  Linux support for WebDAV isn't quite good (but you can fake it with a file manager like Nautilus).